# Program crash on startup and restarts

Tags: python-3.x, sleep-mode

my program runs fine, but sometimes on startup it stops? or crashes? and immediately reloads. I don't know why it's doing that. It's not erroring me. 
and it only started after I added the sleep function.

```
    import time
    print ( "loading cakes.. please wait")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("cakes now loaded - enjoy your program")
    time.sleep(1)

    print ( "Enter a People Name" )
    name = (input())

    print ( "Enter Years of a People, I'll tell you the Years in Doggo : ", end = "")
    ppl = float(input())

    doggo = ppl * 7


    print (name, "Is a People, with a People Years of", ppl, )
    print (name,"'s Age in People Years is", ppl, " and is equal to", doggo, "Doggo Years " )
    time.sleep(2)
    print("(・・；) you're so old")
```

[picture of the thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATI3y.png)

it's not vital I think, but an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you remove the sleep calls? what OS are you on?

Comment: removing sleep just has it run normally, without any crashing. as for OS it's Windows 10. I would like sleep within the program for aesthetic, but if the crashing is not a good thing, sleep can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem once, it was the anti-viruscanner that caused it. It paused the script to check it, and then restarted it once it cleared the scan.

Edit, sry for stuffing the code in the comments. (My version is Python 2.7, but 3.x should be the same)

```
#!c:\Python27\python.exe
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
print ( "loading cakes.. please wait")
time.sleep(3)
print ("cakes now loaded - enjoy your program")
time.sleep(1)
name = raw_input("Enter a People Name\n")
ppl = float(raw_input("Enter Years of a People, I'll tell you the Years in Doggo : "))
doggo = ppl * 7
print ("%s Is a People, with a People Years of %d" %(name, ppl))
print ("%s's Age in People Years is %d and is equal to %d Doggo Years " %(name, ppl, doggo))
time.sleep(2)
print("(・・；) you're so old")
```

Comment: how to fix? and which virus scan :<

Comment: I think it was the avast scanner and the solution was the put the python.exe on the exception list of the scanner.

Comment: I formated your code a little bit, try it if you like.    #!c:\Python27\python.exe
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
print ( "loading cakes.. please wait")
time.sleep(3)
print ("cakes now loaded - enjoy your program")
time.sleep(1)
name = raw_input("Enter a People Name\n")
ppl = float(raw_input("Enter Years of a People, I'll tell you the Years in Doggo : "))
doggo = ppl * 7
print ("%s Is a People, with a People Years of %d" %(name, ppl))
print ("%s's Age in People Years is %d and is equal to %d Doggo Years " %(name, ppl, doggo))
time.sleep(2)
print("(・・；) you're so old")